# VB.NET record not updating

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently trying to update my database records in Access using the code below:

> ```
>     Call connection()
>     With cm
>        .Connection = cn
>        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
>        .CommandText = "Update tblAccount set BALANCE='" & txtBalance.Text & "', where ACCTNO='" & txtPin.Text & "'"
>        dr = .ExecuteNonQuery
>    End With
> ```

However, I'm getting error code: *Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'OleDbDataReader'.* I was able to read and delete records but I'm getting this error when I'm trying to update them.

Comment: Remove  the comma `,`  before where. Anyway is better you use Parameters of DataAdapter to handle with DB.

Comment: You need to post the code where you have declared those objects. `dr` appears to be a DataReader, but `ExecuteNonQuery()` doesn't return a DataReader, as `ExecuteReader()` does, it returns `int`. -- Use `Parameters.Add()` to generate a correct query with parameters, don't concatenate strings, ever.